# How to turn off redisplay of p:password?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with this code:

```html
<h:outputLabel for="password" value="password" />
<p:password id="password" 
                value="#{user.password}"
                required="true" label="password"
                feedback="true"
                minLength="1"                                                    
                requiredMessage="Enter password"/>
<p:message for="password" />
```

The submitted password is redisplayed after submit. How can I avoid this from managed bean on?

Comment: The `<h:inputSecret>` does that **by default** which can be controlled by `redisplay="true"`. I checked for such attribute in `<p:password>`, but it doesn't seem to be implemented. You might want to post an issue report to PF guys so that you can avoid view-specific boilerplate in the bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly call `setPassword("")` from the `login()` method as soon as you retrieved the password.

Answer (score 0):

Store password in `@RequestScoped` scope just to check